# I don't understand why repository does query in one case but doesn't do in another

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-websocket

I have some simple STOMP WebSocket based on spring-boot  and data-jpa from DB.

Query in my controller works fine if it is query from JS (SockJS) and doesn't work (just return empty list) if doing query from Android (com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid) BUT methods from super class CrudRepository (like findAll() ) work too in both cases.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

  @Autowired
  private MemberDAO memberDAO;

      @MessageMapping("/getMembers")
      @SendToUser("/topic/greetings")
      public SocketResponse getMembers(String email){
        System.out.println("email "+memberDAO.findByEmail(email));//Works if it is query from JS (SockJS) and doesn't work (just return rmpty list) if doing query from Android (com.github.NaikSoftware:StompProtocolAndroid) 
        System.out.println("listMembert "+memberDAO.findAll());//Both cases work fine and return list of members 
        //.....
      }
}
```

**DAO**

```
public interface MemberDAO extends CrudRepository<Member, Long> {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    //@Query(" from Member m where m.email = ?1")
    List<Member> findByEmail(String email);

}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ WebSocketConfig.class })
public class Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }

}
```

Any idea? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you check if email is passed in the case the query does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The code is incomplete, there's no spring boot stomp configuration and you don't specify how you persist the object response.

I'm working on an Android stomp over WebSocket client. I suggest you check what the client the receive and how it payload string is converted into the object.

My project is still a work in progress, but it could be useful, I hope.

- [spring boot backend](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi-backend)
- [android client](https://github.com/xcesco/reversi-android)

The question is old, but I hope my answer can help who works with WebSocket.